# How do I add a project manager to Vim?

Tags: vim, project, vim-plugin

Thanks for letting me know I can change my posts this way. I am actually done with adding the project manager to my liking but now I am trying to ad snipmate to my plugins now entirely sure how though.

Comment: Or perhaps how to add nerdtree onto vim on windows?

Comment: the NERDtree isn't bad, but the project plugin is far more powerful (e.g. in.vim and out.vim being sourced every time you enter or leave a project buffer).

Comment: do you know that you could edit your original post and ask further questions there?

Answer (score 1):

The project plugin needs a project file in your `$HOME` directory called `.vimproject`. A sample entry could be as follows on Windows (if you're using linux, replace `vimfiles`with `.vim`):

```
VIMSTUFF="~/vimfiles" CD=. flags=r {
  ../_vimrc
  ../_gvimrc
  plugin/my_plugin.vim
  after/syntax/c.vim
}
```

This *project* holds all my vim related files that I created such as `my_plugin.vim` and `after/syntax/c.vim`.

To edit the `.vimprojects` file, open up vim and press `F12` which will toggle the project window.

The documentation of the project plugin provides a few samples that will guide you how to start.

Comment: to find your home dir in VIM type :echo $HOME

Comment: The `F12` isn't available by default. I think eckes has it mapped to `:Project`.